# Where do a UITableView's section footers get their width?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am having an issue where the section footers for my UITableView are not taking up the full width of the table view. I have a custom cell that uses the text label for a descriptor and the accessory view for a UISwitch. It seems like the footer is using the width of the content view of these cells (though I should note it's slightly off), which does not include the accessory view.

[Here's an image of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIhhu.png)

Is there something that is known to cause this that I can fix without having to do some weird workaround? I only phrase it this way as I just want the default behavior.

Comment: I would add adjust the background colors of your views for debugging purposes just to be sure that the label isn't just word-wrapping. Also, can you post some code or a screen shot of relevant storyboard settings?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in a sample table view and it worked for me very well. I will just post what I did and maybe you can check if you have done the same.

Firstly, I set the Table View Style to grouped in the Interface builder:

[image: Grouped style for table view]

Next, code for the table view data source and delegate methods:

```
ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Cell implementation here
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "DATES"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "If both a delivery date and notification date are chosen, the notification date must be after the delivery date."
    }
}
```

**Note**

- Use `tableView(_:, titleForHeaderInSection:)` and `tableView(_:, titleForFooterInSection:)` for simple text as header and footer
- Use `tableView(_:, viewForHeaderInSection:)` and `tableView(_:, viewForFooterInSection:)` when you need a non-text header and footer or a complex header/footer.